# Replacing class name with an alias

Tags: c++, c++11, type-alias

C++11 type alias is great and I use it a lot but recently I've been wondering why type aliasing doesn't work like such:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Y
{
    public:
    Y(): t( T{} ) {}
    T getT() const;

    private:
    T t;
};

template< typename T>
using Foo = Y<T>;

template< typename T>
T Y<T>::getT() const { return t; } //FINE

/* NOT FINE!
template< typename T>
T Foo<T>::getT() const { return t; }
*/

int main()
{
    Y<int> f{};
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

If a type is aliased, why can't we replace the type aliased with the new alias name?

Comment: `Foo` is `Y<T>` what will `Foo<T>` be?

Comment: You are facing the template deduction problem. How is `Foo<T>` supposed to be deduced?!

Comment: In the vast majority of cases this would be meaningless. `template<class> using Foo = void; template<class T> using Vec = vector<T, my_allocator<T>>;`. It doesn't seem like it's worth the specification complexity to permit this one special case, especially as it does make some sense to require you to use the actual name of a class when defining a member of said class.

Comment: @billz no, `Foo<T>` is `Y<T>`, `Foo` is not a type. `Foo<T>` and `Y<T>` are types (the same type).

Comment: Both clang and MSVC compile the supposedly bad version of program, so it isn't quite clear whether it's indeed NOT FINE.